# Can I send **kwargs in place of set parameter in requests.post?

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, keyword-argument

I'm trying to set up a base class that contains common REST methods, to be used by more specific methods in a later testing framework. I decided that instead of creating different `request.post` methods that correspond to to the user passing in `data`, `json`, or `files` parameters, I would make one method that has the set parameters of url and header and let the user pass in whatever else they want within **kwargs. However, I'm not sure I can even use *kwargs in this context, as it seems the `requests` module expects a positional argument.  This is what I have so far:

```
class Action:

    def __init__(self, url, requestHeaders, **kwargs):
        self.url = url
        self.requestHeaders = requestHeaders
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def postAction(self):
        response = requests.post(self.url, headers=self.requestHeaders, self.kwargs)
        resultCode = response.status_code
        resultMessage = response.text
        print(resultCode)
        print(resultMessage)
        return  resultCode,resultMessage
```

For example, `kwargs` might contain `files={'csv': ('/path/to/csv.csv', open('csv.csv, 'rb'), 'text/csv')}` and `verify=false`.  In another request, `files` might be replaced with `data`. However, when I try to test, I end up with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/test/action.py", line 24
    response = requests.post(self.url, headers=self.requestHeaders, self.kwargs)

SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: You need `**` when *calling* to expand the dictionary, otherwise you're just passing it as one positional argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `kwargs` to be treated as keyword arguments given to `post`, you need to use `**` to apply them:

```
response = requests.post(self.url, headers=self.requestHeaders, **self.kwargs)
```

This, similar to sequence unpacking (`*seq`), will cause the data to be "expanded" into the argument list of the call.